# How to allow only phone number at intl-tel-input?

Tags: jquery, intl-tel-input

I have used [International Telephone Input](https://intl-tel-input.com/) at my webpage. The problem is, user can type anything at the `<input type="tel">`. But, if you look on this [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/learner73/fyo4ubvf/43/), you will see that user can type only plus sign as first character, they have to type number for the remaining. Also, if you copy this, '`+880 1x xxxxxxxx` ' and paste on that input, it'll keep only '`+880 1`' How to do that? I am not seeing any additional code for achieving that feature in that fiddle. Can you please take a look on my fiddle and tell me what I can do to achieve those?

[**My Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/x1expqd1/36/)

Comment: the two links jQuery code are completely different. That's why your code not working as expected. Compare and change yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Input type tel is used to mobile devices to change the custom keyboard to number keyboard.

developer.mozilla.org says *inputs of type tel are functionally identical to standard text inputs*

Unlike `input type="email"` and `input type="url"` , the input value is not automatically validated to a particular format before the form can be submitted.
So you have to do a normal regex on the text input.

You can find additional info here:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel

And about the initial FIddle link, that seems to use some bootstrap classes which can do what you want, take a look here:

http://js.nicdn.de/bootstrap/formhelpers/docs/phone.html